# Why did the ex-magicans in Acts 19:19 burn an enormously expensive amount of books?

Tags: acts, money

Acts 19:19 reads (NKJV, emphasis mine):

> Also, many of those who had practiced magic brought their books together and **burned** them in the sight of all. And they counted up the value of them, and it totaled **fifty thousand pieces of silver**.

That's a lot of money! Why did they burn it all away when they could have just sold the books instead? It appears the point is that anything a Christian possesses that is sinful shouldn't merely be sold, because selling something places it in the hands of others who will sin by it. I can see this principle having many applications when it comes to sinful things which a Christian might possess.

Of course, sound applications can't be made without sound exegesis, so why did they burn away the magic books? Is my interpretation of their reason accurate?

Answer (score 2):

There are several things to consider here:

**1. The word περίεργος (periergos)**

This adjective occurs only twice in the NT, Acts 19:19 and 1 Tim 5:13.  BDAG gives quite different meanings to each occurrence:

- 1 Tim 5:13 - pertaining to paying attention to matters that do not concern one, of persons, meddlesome, officious, curious, substantive: a busybody.
- Acts 19:19 - pertaining to undue misdirected curiosity ... as in the practice of magic, belonging to magic.

The context of Acts 19:19 makes it clear such περίεργος (periergos) practices (details are not known today) were completely inconsistent with the Christian life, ethics and morals.

There appears to be a partial description of some the practices of these magic arts by Clement of Alexandria in "Stromata" book V chapter 8 - see the text here >> http://www.logoslibrary.org/clement/stromata/508.html

**2. Why not sell?**

The expensive books were not sold and the profits given to the church, but publicly burned.  [Contrast Acts 4:34, 37, 5:4, John 12:5, where less controversial things are sold.]  The decision of the book owners not to sell is similar to that faced by any Christian who owns something that they come to believe is inconsistent with their Christian morals such as:

- If a Christian owns illicit drugs, should they be sold or destroyed?
- If a new Christian owns a brothel, should the business be sold or closed and the prostitutes set free?  (this could be very tricky either way!!)
- If a Christian owns (this is controversial) a gun and does not believe this is consistent with Christian morals (not all do!) should they sell or destroy the gun?
- If a Christian owed a slave (this is possible in some places still) should the slave be sold or set free?

These are personal moral questions about which the Bible makes no explicit statements.  The decision is a matter for the individual in consultation with the Holy Spirit.

**3. Public Burning**

Note that in Acts 19 the owners of the books burned them very publicly to obviously make a public spectacle and public statement about their beliefs.  There are possibly several reasons for this such as:

- the book owners wanted to show publicly their new-found faith and new values and morals
- The group of such owners were possibly part of a local guild of such people and if many of them abandoned their secret practices, the market for such materials was very limited
- It was a show public display that what they once valued was now, in their minds, valueless - they now worshiped a much greater and more powerful God (see Acts 19:12, 16) - the true God of heaven.

The reasons for the burning are not stated but one or more of the above is very likely.

Barnes succinctly sums this up when he observes:

> *And burned them before all men* - Publicly. Their arts and offences had been public, and they sought now to undo the evil, as much as lay
> in their power, as extensively as they had done it.

Matthew Poole is more specific:

> *Brought their books together, and burned them*: these books were not sold, and the price of them brought unto the apostles, because it was
> looked upon as the price of a whore, which was an abomination, and
> might not be offered unto God, Deu 23:18.

Ellicott offers an interesting historic comparison:

> The deep-ingrained superstition of the people was treated, as it were,
> homœopathically. Charms and names were allowed to be channels of
> renovation, but were shown to be so by no virtue of their own, but
> only as being media between the Divine power on the one hand and the
> faith of the receiver on the other; and so the disease was cured. The
> student of the history of Florence cannot help recalling the analogous
> scene in that city, when men and women, artists and musicians, brought
> the things in which they most delighted—pictures, ornaments, costly
> dresses—and burnt them in the Piazza of St. Mark at the bidding of
> Savonarola.

Answer (score 1):

The principle you draw …”that anything a Christian possesses that is sinful shouldn't merely be sold”, is an example of ‘drawing out a meaning from text that may *sound right*, but isn’t actually there - eisegesis. So let’s exegete this passage, as well as considering the historical context which will help make sense of this passage.

The Greek word used for “curious arts” is “PERIERGOS.” It is a compound word of “PERI,” meaning “properly, through (all over), i.e. around” and “ERGON,” meaning “toil (as an effort or occupation); by implication, an act” (Strong�s Concordance). Therefore, PERIERGOS means “a work about...‘busy about trifles’” (Vine’s Expository Dictionary). It was a technical term for magic. This word was translated “busybodies” in 1 Timothy 5:13.

Paul had encountered those who were operating in witchcraft before. Paul spoke judgment on Elymas the sorcerer during his first missionary journey (Acts 13:6-11), and on his second journey, he cast a spirit of divination out of a girl in Philippi (Acts 16:16-18). Neither of these two people are mentioned in Scripture as having repented; however, Philip, the evangelist, did see Simon the sorcerer converted (Acts 8:9-13).

There are numerous examples of witchcraft in the Old Testament among the pagans. The Pharaoh of Egypt, during the Jews’ captivity, had his own court magicians (Exodus 7:11, 22; 8:7, and 18-19), two of which were named in 2 Timothy 3:8. The Scriptures also mention the rulers of Babylon as having court magicians, astrologers, and sorcerers (Daniel 2:2, 4:7, and 5:7).

Witchcraft was also commonplace in the land of Canaan among the people whom the Lord drove out before the Israelites. The Lord specifically commanded the Jews not to adopt their practices. In Deuteronomy 18:9-14, He mentioned by name the different curious arts that were forbidden (see also Leviticus 19:26 and 31). King Saul was killed by God because he used a medium to perform a seance (1 Chronicles 10:13-14). In the Old Testament, the Lord commanded that those who practiced such things should be put to death (Leviticus 20:6 and 27).

So let’s consider a more arguable conclusion to take from these verses This clearly reveals that the first-century Christians saw witchcraft and Christianity as being incompatible. Those who try to mix the two today are denying the practice of the early church, as well as the teachings of Scripture.

[Footnote]The estimates on exactly how much money this equals today vary greatly from $1,000 (Rienecker/Rogers) to $32,000 (Dake). It is very hard to place an exact amount on some of the Bible’s monetary figures. Suffice it to say, this must have been a considerable amount, and it must have made quite an impression on all the inhabitants of Ephesus.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP asked, "Is my interpretation of their reason accurate?", but you didn't even touch on his interpretation! -1

Comment: @Rajesh I understand that my explanation won’t satisfy you - but nevertheless - … The OP stated “*It appears the point is that anything a Christian possesses that is sinful shouldn't merely be sold, because selling something places it in the hands of others who will sin by it*” - and I outlined that *this* was *not* the point of this passage in Acts 19, it is *not* what it was ‘saying’. I did this BY outlining what the passage ‘was saying’.

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is right. The reason why sinful things are destroyed because owner completely detests & abhors them. It should be a detailed study about what such things might be in our lives and how is our attitude towards sin. A newborn believer may not consider it much and he would pass on his stash of alcohol, cigarettes, weed to his friends after deciding to abstain from them. But a mature Saint would abhor them and would not let others be defiled by them. And such mature saints also do not let others indulging in such intoxication like tobacco into their church. To understand the reason better, I think the exposition of the background is needed.

> Jude 1:23: “save others by snatching them out of the fire; to others show mercy with fear, hating even the garment stained by the flesh.”(ESV)

Should we be hating even the clothes defiled by the heretics who visited our house and burn them? Are we keeping the defiled books of the lawless false prophets & preachers in our home and sharing false gospels to others? These are the issues to discern depending on our conscience & maturity.

I have seen testimonies of converts about how they started becoming severely sick and then later realized that the reason of the curse is that they hadn't gotten rid of the Hindu idols and objects of worship after converting. The objects of sin are to be dedicated for destruction as cursed to the Lord. The idea of dedicating (substitutional) sin offerings is to rid of the sin by destroying it, otherwise we face the same destruction.

> Deuteronomy 7:25-26: “The carved images of their gods you shall burn with fire. You shall not covet the silver or the gold that is on them or take it for yourselves, lest you be ensnared by it, for it is an abomination to the LORD your God. And you shall not bring an abominable thing into your house and become devoted to destruction like it. You shall utterly detest and abhor it, for it is devoted to destruction.”

> Leviticus 27:28-29: ““But no devoted thing that a man devotes to the LORD, of anything that he has, whether man or beast, or of his inherited field, shall be sold or redeemed; every devoted thing is most holy to the LORD. No one devoted, who is to be devoted for destruction from mankind, shall be ransomed; he shall surely be put to death.”

I think the idols can be sold if they expensive for money, since it is no different than selling the melted gold & silver in it which has been permitted. The idols if sold to other idolaters will not make them more sinful, but the books of divination are black magic objects used for evil works. Those should not be sold for a profit. The objects of your black magic, astrology, superstition, heresies and charms cannot be compared to expensive idols of gold from which you can make profit. The expensive idols by themselves mean nothing more than stones but the books of satanic divination contain real power of the evil world.

> Joshua 6:17-19: “And the city and all that is within it shall be devoted to the LORD for destruction. Only Rahab the prostitute and all who are with her in her house shall live, because she hid the messengers whom we sent. But you, keep yourselves from the things devoted to destruction, lest when you have devoted them you take any of the devoted things and make the camp of Israel a thing for destruction and bring trouble upon it. But all silver and gold, and every vessel of bronze and iron, are holy to the LORD; they shall go into the treasury of the LORD.””

> Joshua 7:10-15: “The LORD said to Joshua, “Get up! Why have you fallen on your face? Israel has sinned; they have transgressed my covenant that I commanded them; they have taken some of the devoted things; they have stolen and lied and put them among their own belongings. Therefore the people of Israel cannot stand before their enemies. They turn their backs before their enemies, because they have become devoted for destruction. I will be with you no more, unless you destroy the devoted things from among you. Get up! Consecrate the people and say, ‘Consecrate yourselves for tomorrow; for thus says the LORD, God of Israel, “There are devoted things in your midst, O Israel. You cannot stand before your enemies until you take away the devoted things from among you.” In the morning therefore you shall be brought near by your tribes. And the tribe that the LORD takes by lot shall come near by clans. And the clan that the LORD takes shall come near by households. And the household that the LORD takes shall come near man by man. And he who is taken with the devoted things shall be burned with fire, he and all that he has, because he has transgressed the covenant of the LORD, and because he has done an outrageous thing in Israel.’””

The word for devoted (for destruction) is anathema in Greek. It is a good time to meditate upon the Passover (Feast of unleavened bread), no leavened item is allowed to be found in the home for a week. This show the level of strict emphasis to remove the leaven. There's a tradition where children are to find the ten breadcrumbs hidden to be destroyed; and the whole house is thoroughly cleaned until the Passover. This ceremonial search for cleaning the leavened [(Bedikat chametz)](https://hebrew4christians.com/Holidays/Spring_Holidays/Pesach/Chametz/chametz.html) depicts removal of sins. The leavened breadcrumbs are completely burned the next day with the formal declaration of disowning and denouncing any leaven, cf. 1Cor 5:6-8.

By putting the sin to death & destruction as dedication to God, we obtain blessing, otherwise we will receive the destruction along with the sin.